# How to propogate tags to an ECS Task launched from an EventBridge Target?

Tags: tags, amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I have a EventBridge (previously CloudWatch Events) [`Rule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_Rule.html) and [`Target`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_Target.html) that are used to launch ECS [`Task`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_Task.html)s on a [schedule (cron)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html). I would like to apply some tags to the Task.

I tried including tags in [`RegisterTaskDefinition`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RegisterTaskDefinition.html), but this did not result in any tags being set on the `Task`s, as [`RunTask`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html) does not propagate tags if [`propagateTags`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html#ECS-RunTask-request-propagateTags) is unspecified.

[`PutTargets`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutTargets.html) is the action to create the event target that will eventually call [`RunTask`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html). I searched in `ecsParameters` ([`EcsParameters`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_EcsParameters.html)) and `input` ([`TaskOverride`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_TaskOverride.html)) for fields that would correspond to either `tags` or `propagateTags` from [`RunTask`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html) but I could not find any corresponding fields.

Is there any way to apply tags to an ECS Task that is run from an EventBridge rule target?

2021-06-24 update (thanks @baxang): EventBridge has added `ecsParameters.PropagateTags: "TASK_DEFINITION"` to the API documentation and to some SDKs yesterday ([containers-roadmap#89](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/89))!

- python [botocore 1.20.99](https://github.com/boto/botocore/commit/df7892410ef7d7f4312eb5da520ecaec5ea1ffdd)
- js [aws-sdk v2.933.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/commit/d420427503fcfe7854d191c055e4a034fcfa9fdd)
- js [@aws-sdk/client-eventbridge 3.20.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/v3.20.0/clients/client-eventbridge/models/models_0.ts#L3321) [@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-events 3.20.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/v3.20.0/clients/client-cloudwatch-events/models/models_0.ts#L3321) (2021-07-01 [commit](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/commit/ed301ba3c10decdd84fb79ddc7ccf5c87072e7b9#diff-5bb96cc51ff37d9f83094da52f1fdc59e5c63a66d92264ab7778b0f1a8126833))
- [aws-sdk-go v1.38.66](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/pull/3974)
- [aws-sdk-go-v2/service/eventbridge 1.7.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/v1.7.0/service/eventbridge/types/types.go#L498), [aws-sdk-go-v2/service/cloudwatchevents 1.7.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/v1.7.0/service/cloudwatchevents/types/types.go#L498) (2021-06-25 [commit](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/commit/d96de3a427321579a75bde4d817adc171b67709c))
- java [com.amazonaws aws-java-sdk-eventbridge 1.12.11](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/1.12.11/aws-java-sdk-eventbridge/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/eventbridge/model/EcsParameters.java#L953) ([commit](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/commit/524a2847f7900ffb8e96e38b4652932b220ee5f6))
- java [software.amazon.awssdk eventbridge 2.16.98](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/2.16.98/services/eventbridge/src/main/resources/codegen-resources/service-2.json#L2336-L2339) ([commit](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/commit/287c2e5348c4bdc17242d7d66ef82bf47012f003))
- .Net [AWSSDK.EventBridge 3.7.68.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/3.7.68.0/sdk/src/Services/EventBridge/Generated/Model/EcsParameters.cs#L261), [AWSSDK.CloudWatchEvents 3.7.68.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/3.7.68.0/sdk/src/Services/CloudWatchEvents/Generated/Model/EcsParameters.cs#L261) ([commit](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/commit/204af0a14ab1c57266f58dda846c02a1001e87fb))
- terraform provider aws [aws_cloudwatch_event_target](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target#propagate_tags) ([source](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/aws/resource_aws_cloudwatch_event_target.go)) ([#19975](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/19975), part of the [2021-07-15 v3.50.0 release](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/releases/tag/v3.50.0))
- CloudFormation [AWS::Events::Rule EcsParameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-ecsparameters.html) ([2021-09-22](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudformation-user-guide/blob/ff37a78d55fc0b1f85bc5a4b69d2e1b4e7938201/doc_source/aws-properties-events-rule-ecsparameters.md))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the API has `propagateTags` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_EcsParameters.html#eventbridge-Type-EcsParameters-PropagateTags so if you are launching the task via API, there seems to be a way.

CloudFormation however does not support the property: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-ecsparameters.html. This issue([link](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/394)) on [aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation) repo seems to be related.